# laravel_session cookie doesn't set

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, browser, session-cookies

When I connect to ABC network the `laravel_session` cookie is not set, though the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie is set. When I change the connection to XYZ network, both the cookies are set properly.

If the cookie is not set, I get `TokenMismatchException`.

Is there any way to find out what might be causing this or is there any workaround?